# AWS EC2 Node.js Application with Winston Logger Integration Resulting in 502 Error for Specific Route

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, winston

I'm facing a perplexing issue with my Node.js application running on an AWS EC2 instance. After integrating the Winston logger into my application, I started encountering a 502 error, but only for a specific route. To narrow it down, I added a simple log statement (logger.info('Login request')) within that particular route.

Here's the strange part: The 502 error only occurs for this specific route, while the rest of the application works flawlessly. However, when I check the AWS logs, I can see that the log message ("Login request") is indeed present. Additionally, the same codebase, with the Winston logger integration, runs perfectly without any errors when deployed on Heroku with a test domain.

I'm baffled by this issue and would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve it. It's essential for me to have logging properly functioning on AWS EC2, as it is in the Heroku environment.

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Winston Code:**

```
const winston = require("winston");
const { combine, timestamp, errors, splat, json, colorize, simple } = winston.format
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
const appRoot = require("app-root-path");

var transport = new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
    filename: appRoot + '/logs/log-%DATE%.log',
    datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    zippedArchive: true,
    maxSize: '20m',
    maxFiles: '14d'
});
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: "silly",
    format: combine(
        timestamp({ format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" }),
        errors({ stack: true }),
        splat(),
        json()
    ),
    transports: [
        transport
    ]
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "development") {

    logger.add(new winston.transports.Console({
        format: combine(
            colorize(),
            simple()
        )
    }));
}
```

**Router code:**

```
router.get('/patient/login',forwardAuthenticated, patientAuth.patientloginoptimized);
```

**Request handler:**

```
exports.patientloginoptimized = (req, res, next) => {
    logger.info('Patient login request')
    res.render('patientViews/patientFront/patient-login-optimized', {
        title: "",
    })
}
```

Comment: Does the application have permission to `appRoot + '/logs/log-%DATE%.log'1`? Can you check with a `Console` transport alone and see if the issue persists?

Comment: Yes, it has, even though the log file is being created along with the text I logged into that specific route.

Comment: Share the code of your lambda. Probably nothing to do with your logger then

Comment: @RobinThomas
Here's the router code:
`router.get('/patient/login',forwardAuthenticated, patientAuth.patientloginoptimized);`
and here's the handler:
`exports.patientloginoptimized = (req, res, next) => {
    logger.info('Patient login request')
    res.render('patientViews/patientFront/patient-login-optimized', {
        title: "",
    })
}`

Comment: Please add it to the question.